# Python feedparser module error

Tags: python, rss, python-2.x, feedparser

python feedparser not parsing . "it gives me error that object has no attribute image."

rss feed:

```
thenews = 'https://www.thenews.com.pk/rss/1/1'
```

this does not work:

```
d = feedparser.parse(thenews)
print d.feed.image
```

Comment: Have you tried `d.image`?

Comment: yes, same error.

Comment: What version of FeedParser? Are you sure there is a `.parse`? Have you inspected the API docs for these refs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the feed you’re using does not include an image. If you

`print d.feed`

you’ll see the available fields for the feed. Or you can see that by looking directly at the source `https://www.thenews.com.pk/rss/1/1` (there’s no `image` tag for the `channel`).

Comment: but if you go to the rssfeed link, there is an <image> tag under channel/item.

Comment: There is for indiviual `item`s, not for the channel (feed).

Comment: so I am able to get titles out of individual items, i wanted to get image as well for individual items. which I am not able to

Comment: That's another issue, not stated in your question.

Comment: Check this for reference: https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/issues/48

Comment: my bad, but i am able get d.feed.title
so that is why i was wondering why I can't get d.feed.image

Comment: Check the link I posted.

Comment: i was wondering if there can be a work around till this thing gets implemented? as I cannot use xml parser as the link is a rss feed. any kind of help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You can use any xml parser, rss is just an xml.